# Why is "git pull origin feature-12345 master" the only way to update my pull request branch?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I'm working with a pull request on BitBucket, which has been open for a fairly long time (several weeks, while master continues to progress rapidly), and where I'm not the only person making commits to the PR. I also need to keep the PR in sync with master. Because there are multiple people working on the branch (and because it feels dirty), doing a rebase and then `git push --force` is not a great option.

The only thing that I've found actually works, in this case, is the following:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout -b feature-12345 origin/feature-12345
git pull origin feature-12345 master
git push origin feature-12345
```

The key line above is `git pull origin feature-12345 master`, which results in a commit with the message:

```
Merge branches 'feature-12345' and 'master' of ssh://mybitbucketserver/ABC/xyz into feature-12345
```

After doing this, BitBucket shows a nice "merge" commit in the "commits" list for the PR, instead of flooding the commit history with recent commits from master.

I'm happy that I've worked out how to do this, but my question is: why do I need to use that specific command, to make it merge in this way? If I try (while on the `feature-12345` branch):

```
git pull origin master
```

And then push, it floods my commit history.

Same if I do this (which I would have thought would be 100% equivalent to the merge part of `git pull origin feature-12345 master`, but it seems not):

```
git merge feature-12345 master
```

What's so special about `git pull origin feature-12345 master`?

Comment: The following three commands should work as same: `git pull origin feature-12345 master`, `git pull origin master` (on `feature-12345` branch), `git merge master` (on `feature-12345` branch). Can you show the original commit history and the commit history (which you said flooded) after executing `git pull origin master` separately?

Comment: It's not a good idea to merge `master` to a feature branch. When you'd like to test if `feature-12345` works well with `master`, you could either create a test branch from `master` and merge `feature-12345` to it, or create it from `feature-12345` and merge `master` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git pull` is nothing more than a `fetch` followed by a `merge`.

`git pull feature-12345 master` updates your remote branches `origin/feature-12345` and `origin/master`, then it merges both of these into your current `HEAD`.

I'm not sure why `git pull origin master` makes bitbucket show the whole history of master, my guess is that it gets confused by the merge branch being a remote branch (`origin/master`, compared to just `master`), or possibly because you merge two branches (`origin/master` and `origin/feature-12345`) into a third one (`feature-12345`)

Let me suggest to first get your master up-to-date, merge locally to you branch, then push the resulting branch:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master # keep your master branch up to date
git checkout feature-12345
git merge master # to get new features from master, resolve conflicts...
git push origin feature-12345 # push the merge commit to bitbucket
```

Comment: Thanks @Gauthier, a simple `git merge master` does indeed do the trick, BitBucket shows a single commit (marked with "M" for merge) with message "Merge branch 'master' into feature-12345", and it doesn't show any other commits from master in the PR. I'm still a bit afraid that doing it this way will flood the commit history, but will try it out and will keep an eye on my PR commit histories, fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: what you want is:

```
git fetch origin
```

optionally followed by:

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master   # *do* allow fast-forward here
```

followed by:

```
git checkout feature-12345
git merge origin/feature-12345   # or git rebase origin/feature-12345
```

if needed/desired, followed by:

```
git merge --no-ff origin/master  # or git merge --no-ff master
```

As [ElpieKay points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47279063/why-is-git-pull-origin-feature-12345-master-the-only-way-to-update-my-pull-req#comment81514076_47279063), though, you might want to rethink your strategy of merging *from* the tip commit of master *into* the feature branch.  It's not really *wrong* but subsequently merging the feature branch back into the master branch can result in a criss-cross merge, which Git does handle, but can produce surprises.

#### Description (long)

As [Gauthier answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47280798/1256452), `git pull` simply runs `git fetch` first, then—once that succeeds—`git merge` (or sometimes a different Git command, if you tell it to).

The tricky part is *how* `git pull` runs `git merge`.  It does not do what most people expect at first.

Git's `merge` verb merges *commits*.  The arguments to `git merge` specify *which* commit(s) to use as "their" commit(s).  Your commit, the `--ours` commit in a normal three-way merge, is *always* `HEAD`: whatever commit is current when you first run the command.  The way `git pull` runs its two Git commands, the commit that was current when you ran `git pull` is still current when `git pull` runs `git merge`.

The merge base for an ordinary three-way merge is simple enough; `git merge-base` will compute it for you.  But you're not doing an ordinary three-way merge.  Instead, you're doing what Git calls an *octopus merge*.  To find the merge base for this operation, Git uses `git merge-base --octopus`, giving it the hash ID of the `HEAD` commit and the hash ID of each of the target commits you're asking to merge.  Git then compares this merge base to each commit-to-be-merged, and combines all the changes.

---

When you run:

```
git pull origin feature-12345 master
```

you tell your Git to connect to a second Git over on `origin`, and ask it for *its* `feature-12345` and *its* `master`, by `git pull` running:

```
git fetch origin feature-12345 master
```

These names resolve to two commit hash IDs (probably different ones, but possibly one single one).  If your Git does not yet have these commits, your Git downloads these commits now.  If your Git already has these commits, your Git need not do anything here.

The next step depends on your Git version.  If your Git is 1.8.4 or newer, your Git "opportunistically updates" your `origin/feature-12345` and `origin/master` now.  Otherwise, it leaves them unchanged.

Last, your `git fetch` dumps these raw commit hash IDs into the file `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  The `git fetch` step is now complete.

The `pull` code now moves on to the second Git command: it runs `git merge <hash-id-1> <hash-id-2>`, where the two hash IDs are extracted from the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file.  (It supplies some extra arguments like `-m` to set the default commit message as well, but these are less important here.)  This is what invokes the octopus merge strategy.

Note, again, that Git is doing this merge by *commit hash IDs*, not by names!  This is one reason people can have so much trouble reproducing the effect: those hash IDs *may*, especially if your Git is very old (pre-1.8.4), not have any names at all!

If you just run `git fetch origin`, though, your Git will load, from `origin`, *all* its branches, setting *all* your own `origin/*` remote-tracking names to correspond to the commits on `origin`.  You could then run `git merge origin/feature-12345 origin/master` to get this same octopus merge.

Actually *wanting* octopus merges is pretty rare.  But using the octopus merge strategy has a side effect: it inhibits Git from doing a *fast-forward* operation.  When you run:

```
git merge <single-commit-specifier>
```

Git will check to see if your current commit is an ancestor of the specified commit.  If so, Git *can* do a fast-forward *instead* of a merge.  If you have not told Git *not* do do that, it *will* do that, because it can.

If you want a true merge—to avoid, as you put it, "flooding the commit history"—you can simply tell Git: Don't do that.  The `--no-ff` flag (note double dash) says to `git merge` that even if it *can*, it shouldn't.  If it can't, it won't anyway (in which case the flag is unnecessary but harmless).  If it can, it won't because of the flag: you will get a real merge, rather than a fast-forward not-a-merge-at-all.

Comment: Thanks @torek, `git merge --no-ff origin/master` does the trick, BitBucket shows a single commit (marked with "M" for merge) with message "Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into feature-12345". However, I've accepted the answer from @Gauthier instead of yours, because `git merge master` achieves the same result, and it's a simpler command and results in a simpler commit message. But I'm not sure which is the "more correct" command to use, in this case.

Comment: Well, if you work through how Git actually does merges (see other SO Q&A or a book like [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)), you'll see that `git merge origin/master` merges based on the commit to which `origin/master` points, while `git merge master` merges based on the commit to which `master` points. If both names point to *the same* commit you get the same merge (with slightly different default merge messages). The `--no-ff` prevents the fast-forward merge that you're worried about, and applies in either case.

Comment: What is the problem with merging master into feature branches? That's usually how I solve conflicts, rather that rebase.

Comment: @Gauthier: as I noted, it's not *wrong*, it can just create criss-cross merges (depending on subsequent merges). Some people / organizations prefer a "one way" flow of merges to avoid this and keep the work-flow more comprehensible. But in terms of source code results, "merge Y (while on X)" and "merge X (while on Y)" produce the same result.